# How to automatically redirect to home page after session-timeout

Tags: redirect, liferay, liferay-6, session-timeout, portal

I would like to automatically redirect control to my community home page after session-timeout.

I tried putting below properties in my `portal-ext.properties` file but after session-timeout it doesn't automatically goes to community home page however if I click on any link or button it goes back to home page.

Can anybody please let me know how control can automatically be transffered to home page after session-timeout instead of clicking on any button or link.

```
session.id.delimiter=
session.id.weblogic.delimiter=!
session.timeout=5
session.timeout.warning=1
session.timeout.auto.extend=false
session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true
default.landing.page.path=/web/demo/home
last.modified.check=false
theme.css.fast.load=true
javascript.fast.load=true
hibernate.show_sql=false
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.threadlocal.ThreadLocalFilter=true
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.unsyncprintwriterpool.UnsyncPrintWriterPoolFilter=true
jsp.writer.buffer.size=0
finalize.manager.thread.enabled=true

session.enable.phishing.protection=true
```

**Environment:** Liferay 6.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add/Update below properties to your portal-ext.properties file:

```
default.logout.page.path=/web/guest/home
```

`auth.login.url=/web/guest/home`

Answer (score -1):

default.logout.page.path=/web/guest/home is the url redirected to after the logout.

How to logout and redirect to /web/guest/home automatically after session timeout?At present we are hosting few widgets on the dashboard page. When a user click any of the widget after session timeout, a new tab opens and is redirected to /web/guest/home. How to logout from dashboard page automatically after session timeout

Comment: post question not as answer